# How to extract serialised data from Access

Tags: python, xml, ms-access, serialization

I want to enable a user to export some data to a web application I am building. The data from the legacy application can be accessed through MS Acces (ODBC). The web application is written in Django/Python, but that is not very relevant.

The user would have to export data from time to time and import it into the web app. The table structure in the web app more-or-less mirrors the one in the legacy application.

My question of how to get the data from Access to a format that is easily parseable in the web app. The data is from 5 different tables and interrelated. Is there a way to serialise the data from Access into an XML / JSON file? I know that you can do an XML export, but as far as I know that is limited to a query, so I wouldn't have the hierarchy... Is there a VBA library to help with the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference `Microsoft XML, v5.0` (or whatever version) in the Visual Basic Editor and create XML programmatically.

See
- [Simple example](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1919)
- [Introduction to XML in Microsoft Windows](http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson36.htm) (in depth example)

Comment: Can't test now for lack of MS Access, but I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. I did some googling and it looks like you can export data from a table together with selected other tables. For that, it is necessary to draw the relationships within Access.

That might also solve my problem (and without composing the XML manually). Will find out if this works and check back later.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167823(v=office.11).aspx#odc_accessnewxmlfeatures_includingrelatedtableswhenexportingxml